# Unable to select an element from a child window/box

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am in the process of identifying the elements in this box

[image] 
[image]

•   The dropdown/dialog box/popup/window  with the four options are displayed when               I click
•   Currently this recognized by Selenium using this Xpath – 
    `//*[@id="menu_3"]/img`

```html
<img role="button" src="images/alta/menuDown_act.png" tabindex="5" class="imgPop_ena" height="12" width="12">
```

However, after this I am unable to navigate to one of the options.

Element details of the window:

```html
<div id="menuDiv_0" class="menuDiv" data-domdepth="0" data-activemenuitemid="savedItem_0" style="top: 904px; left: 629.031px; height: 118px; width: 112px;">
```

[image]

•   Below is the element details to select “MATERIAL” from the list

```html
<li id="savedItem_2" tabindex="5" data-menutype="HTML" class="menuItem" role="menuitem" onclick="main.zoneMenuWindow.addLine('W1MT');" onkeypress=" ouaf.context.onMenuKeyPress(event); " onkeydown="ouaf.context.onMenuKeyPress(event)" onmouseover="ouaf.context.expandSubMenu(false)" data-menuobj="CI_ZONEMENU" data-isleaf="true">
    <span data-menutype="HTML" data-menuobj="CI_ZONEMENU">Material</span>
    <span data-menuobj="CI_ZONEMENU"></span>
</li>
```

```
*** Element info:
{Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='menuDiv_0']}
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) –
```

Comment: *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id='menuDiv_0']}
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)

Comment: The below piece of code resolved the issue

Comment: WebElement PR_Material = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Material')]"));
  JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",PR_Material);